# Regrouping dataframe in pandas using a key. Faster way than iterating over rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Summary:

I want to arrange a time-series of codes (large dataset), that represent the start and end of actions, into a Gantt chart, so I need to regroup them into Task (name),  Start (time), and Finish (time) columns. However I can so far only do this very slowly iterating over each rows with a for loop :(

(I've been trying groupby and pivot but I just don't grasp these well enough yet to make them do what I want.)

### Key

I have a 'key' dictionary/df with a **start_code**, **end_code** and an action **label**. Simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
code_key_cols = ["start_code", "end_code", "label"]
code_key = [[1, 2, "a"],
            [3, 4, "b"],
            [5, 6, "c"],
            [7, 8, "d"]]
code_df = pd.DataFrame(code_key, columns=code_key_cols)

Out[]:    start_code  end_code label
      0           1         2     a
      1           3         4     b
      2           5         6     c
      3           7         8     d
```

### Data

Then I have a bunch of data which is just a time series of when these codes. 
I want to organize them in such a way to plot on a gantt chart. 
For plotly that means having a **task**, **start**, **finish** column.

(**Just creating fake data** here for example, mimicing behaviour of the actual data, where the same action type can't happen twice in parallel, only concurrently)

```
from random import shuffle
data = []
for i in range(3000):
    start_codes = [x for x in code_df.iloc[:, 0]]
    end_codes = [x for x in code_df.iloc[:, 1]]
    shuffle(start_codes)
    shuffle(end_codes)
    [data.append(x) for x in start_codes]
    [data.append(x) for x in end_codes]

data_cols = ["code", "time"]
data_df = pd.DataFrame()
data_df['code'] = data
data_df['time'] = pd.date_range(start="19700101", periods=len(data))

print(data_df.head())
   code       time
0     3 1970-01-01
1     1 1970-01-02
2     7 1970-01-03
3     5 1970-01-04
4     2 1970-01-05
```

### My attempt:

I can do it, but only in a very slow way, iterating row by row! I'm sure pandas has a more efficient way of doing this. How would you do it? 
This is how I did it but with a df of 12K rows it takes over 13s :(

```
import numpy as np
lst = []
for _, code_row in code_df.iterrows():
    begin = True
    task = np.nan
    start = np.nan
    finish = np.nan
    for _, data_row in data_df.iterrows():
        if begin:
            if code_row['start_code'] == data_row['code']:
                task = code_row.label
                start = data_row.time
                begin = False
        else:
            if code_row['end_code'] == data_row['code']:
                finish = data_row.time
                begin = True
                lst.append([task, start, finish])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=lst, columns=["Task", 'Start', 'Finish'])
```

### Output

For context I'll show the goal, plotting the Gantt chart with the following code (*changing the for i in range* above from 3000 to 10 for simplification).

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

fig = ff.create_gantt(df3, group_tasks=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: Gantt chart example with 10 iterations]
btw if you read this far thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: if i understand, you have a `key` in `code_df` and you want to create another dataframe with dates starting from that codes min to its max date value?

Comment: No min and max, but each task will start and end multiple times. So finding the next corresponding end_code after its start_code. Hence I thought I could only go row by row. Sorry if that wasn't quite clear! Rubens managed to decode below though and I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. This should give you the same output:

```
# we'll create a new dataframe out of two slices on data_df (resulting in two new dataframes), namely those rows belonging to start_code and those belonging to end_code.
# next, sort the slices on code and time such that our slices match in order (this builds on the concurrent assumption you stated)
# drop unwanted columns and rename others as desired
# reset indices as otherwise pd.concat tries to adhere to the old indices
# merge the labels from code_df

df3_new = pd.concat([
    data_df[data_df.code.isin(code_df.start_code)]
        .sort_values(['code', 'time'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename(columns={'time': 'Start'}),
    data_df[data_df.code.isin(code_df.end_code)]
        .sort_values(['code', 'time'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename(columns={'time': 'Finish'})
        .drop('code', axis=1)
], axis=1) \
    .merge(code_df, how='left', left_on='code', right_on='start_code') \
    .drop(['code', 'start_code', 'end_code'], axis=1) \
    .rename(columns={'label': 'Task'})

# which yields the same outcome (for the given set at least)
df3.equals(df3_new.loc[:, ['Task','Start', 'Finish']])
True
```

With the following average performance on the given set:

```
12.5 ms ± 435 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Very clever, thank you, you understood the exact issue (I felt I struggled to explain). This is indeed about 60X faster than what I was doing. An enormous help.

I see my knowledge-gap was in how .merge() can be used. Very convenient method, I'll be using that more often!